# How to load Post Type fields with data from a remote API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, advanced-custom-fields

I need to bring the information of a Post Type from a Remote URL that show a json file.

My data is:

```
Comarca > Unidade > Setor
```

I need tó load a data from json URL to be selected in the Backend

*Sample of remote url(json)*

```
{
"id": 1,
"nome": "Tribunal de Justiça do Estado do Acre",
"sigla": "TJAC",
"comarcas": [{
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Acrelândia",
        "sigla": "AL",
        "unidades": [{
                    "id": 24,
                    "nome": "Direção do Foro",
                    "sigla": "ALDFO",
                    "setor": [{
                            "id": 28,
                            "nome": "Vara Cível",
                            "sigla": "ACVCI",
                            "tipo": "VARA"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "nome": "Vara Criminal",
                            "sigla": "ACVCR",
                            "tipo": "VIRTUAL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "tipo": "ADMINISTRATIVA",
                ]
            }
            [{
                "id": 2,
                "nome": "Rio Branco",
                "sigla": "RB",
                "unidades": [{
                    "id": 24,
                    "nome": "Direção do Foro",
                    "sigla": "ALDFO",
                    "setor": [{
                            "id": 28,
                            "nome": "Central de Execução de Penas e Medidas Alternativas",
                            "sigla": "BRCEPAL",
                            "tipo": "VARA"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "nome": "Juizado Especial Criminal",
                            "sigla": "BRJECRIM",
                            "tipo": "VIRTUAL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "tipo": "ADMINISTRATIVA"
                }]
            }]
    }
}
```

This information will be loaded into WP-Admin to allow user selection when Filling in custom fields on a page.

Field "Comarca" => receive [comarca]

Field "Unidade" => receive [unidade]

Field "sertor" => receive [nome] after selecting [comarca] and [unidade] dynamically

Field “sigla” => receive [sigla]

Field "Tipo" => receive [tipo]

```
My Custom Fields Created in ACF

if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_6100ec8d1bf79',
    'title' => 'Lotação',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_6100f04affa8f',
            'label' => 'Nome',
            'name' => 'nome',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Nome da Unidade',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Nome da Unidade',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_6100f3c5ffa91',
            'label' => 'Sigla',
            'name' => 'sigla',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Informar a Sigla da Unidade',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => 6,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_6100f076ffa90',
            'label' => 'Comarca',
            'name' => 'comarca',
            'type' => 'taxonomy',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'taxonomy' => 'comarca',
            'field_type' => 'checkbox',
            'add_term' => 0,
            'save_terms' => 0,
            'load_terms' => 0,
            'return_format' => 'id',
            'multiple' => 0,
            'allow_null' => 0,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_6100f421ffa92',
            'label' => 'Tipo',
            'name' => 'tipo',
            'type' => 'select',
            'instructions' => 'Selecionar Administrativo | Primeiro Grau | Segundo Grau',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'choices' => array(
                'ad' => 'Administrativo',
                'pg' => 'Primeiro Grau',
                'sg' => 'Segundo Grau',
            ),
            'default_value' => 'ad',
            'allow_null' => 0,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'ui' => 0,
            'return_format' => 'array',
            'ajax' => 0,
            'placeholder' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_61035043400f1',
            'label' => 'Id Parent',
            'name' => 'id_parent',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'lotacao',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

**I’m researching an implementation model that makes this possible.**

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use `XMLHttpRequest` for pass `JSON` data as `POST`.